# OSPF broadcast link - forming adjacenices between non-DR hosts

Tags: routing, ospf

In an OSPF broadcast configuration, can some host (H1) form an adjacency with another host(H2) that is not DR. For example H1 does not see for some reason the DR advertised by the H2. Does standard mandate forming adjacency with DR only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by adjacency, you mean a Full adjacency, then on a broadcast or NBMA medium, a router only achieves a Full adjacency with the DR and BDR (of course, the DR and BDR should have a Full adjacency with all the routers). The router will not get past the 2-Way state (bi-directional communication has been established) with any other routers.

A Full adjacency means that two routers have exchanged LSAs, but a router on a broadcast or NBMA medium only exchanges LSAs with the DR and BDR, so it will not form a Full adjacency with any other routers on that medium.

A broadcast medium implies that every router can see every other router on the medium.

On NBMA, you need to be careful. You should set it up as a hub and spoke topology, and the DR should be at the hub so that all the other routers can see it (the DR and BDR *must* have access to all the other routers). You could also use something like subinterfaces configured as point-to-point links so that there is no DR or BDR.

Comment: Seams to answer the question.